# How to pass parameters to SQL script via Powershell

Tags: sql, shell, powershell

I have a Power-shell script that calls a SQL script. This is currently working, but inside my sql script I have some hard coded parameters that I would like to pass to the SQL script via the powershell.

So this is the snip-it from the Power-shell script

```
function ExecSqlScript([string] $scriptName)
{
$scriptFile = $script:currentDir + $scriptName
$sqlLog = $script:logFileDir + $scriptName + "_{0:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}.log" -f (Get-Date)
$result = sqlcmd -S uk-ldn-dt270 -U sa -P passwordhere3! -i $scriptFile -b | Tee-Object -             filepath $sqlLog

 if ($result -like "*Msg *, Level *, State *" -Or $result -like "*Sqlcmd: Error:*") 
    {
    throw "SQL script " + $scriptFile + " failed: " + $result
    }   
}

try
{
    ExecSqlScript "restoreDatabase.sql"
}
catch
{
 //Some Error handling here
}
```

And this is from the SQL

```
USE MASTER
GO
DECLARE @dbName varchar(255)
SET @dbName = 'HardCodedDatabaseName'
```

So I want to pass the value for dbName, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just in case someone else needs to do this... here is a working example.

Power Shell Script:

```
sqlcmd -S uk-ldn-dt270 -U sa -P 1NetNasdf£! -v db = "'DatabaseNameHere'" -i $scriptFile -b | Tee-Object -filepath $sqlLog
```

Note the -v switch to assign the variables

And here is the MS SQL:

```
USE MASTER
GO

if db_id($(db)) is null

BEGIN
    EXEC('
    RESTORE DATABASE ' + $(db) + '
    FROM DISK = ''D:\DB Backup\EmptyLiveV5.bak''
    WITH MOVE ''LiveV5_Data'' TO ''C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\LiveV5_' + $(db) + '.MDF'',
    MOVE ''LiveV5_Log'' To ''C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\LiveV5_' + $(db) + '_log.LDF'', REPLACE,
    STATS =10')
END
```

Note: You do not have to assign the scripting varible to a normal sql varible like this.

```
SET @dbName = $(db)
```

you can just use it in your sql code. - Happy coding.

Comment: It's better to use the sql variable since that helps to prevent against sql injection

Answer (score 13):

You could take advantage of sqlcmd's [scripting variables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx). Those can be used in script file and are marked with `$()`. Like so,

```
-- Sql script file
use $(db);
select someting from somewhere;
```

When calling `sqlcmd`, use the `-v` parameter to assign variables. Like so,

```
sqlcmd -S server\instance -E -v db ="MyDatabase" -i s.sql
```

*Edit*

Mind the Sql syntax when setting variables. Consider the following script:

```
DECLARE @dbName varchar(255)
SET @dbName = $(db)
select 'val' = @dbName
```

As passed to the Sql Server, it looks like so (Profiler helps here):

```
use master;

DECLARE @dbName varchar(255)
SET @dbName = foo
select 'val' = @dbName
```

This is, obviously invalid a syntax, as `SET @dbName = foo` won't make much sense. The value ought to be within single quotes like so,

```
sqlcmd -S server\instance -E -v db ="'foo'" -i s.sql
```

Comment: Ok this is what my sql looks like now >> SET @dbName = $(db) and the Powershell script > $result = sqlcmd -S uk-ldn-dt270 -U sa -P jjj88J! -v db ="LiveV5_V2_Integration_Ayo" -i $scriptFile -b | Tee-Object -filepath $sqlLog and now I am getting an invalid column error and it saying the invalid column is the value I am trying to pass in..hmmm

Comment: @user2537315 You are missing single quotes. See updated post.

Comment: @vonPrzy its working now... thanks. Marking as correct! Surprised I have not been voted up... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full example using a different PowerShell approach. Here I'm using a specific script to reset local databases for a clean development environment.

```
## Reset the Database
$resetScript= "C:\ResetSite\resetDatabases.sql"
Write-Host "Resetting the DB - Running $($resetScript)"
$connectionString = "Server = localhost; Database = 'master'; UID = myusername; PWD = mypassword"

# Create variables & params
$sqlCmdVariables = @(
    "Database=$($siteConfig.db_name)",
    "UserName=$($siteConfig.db_username)",
    "UserPassword=$($siteConfig.db_user_password)"
)
$sqlCmdParameters = @{
    InputFile = $resetScript
    QueryTimeout = 1800
    ConnectionString = $connectionString
    Variable = $sqlCmdVariables
}
# Invoke
Invoke-SqlCmd @sqlCmdParameters
```

The .sql file then uses the parameters passed in, the same way @nmbell mentions.

```
-- Declare the vars
DECLARE @Database nvarchar(100), @UserName nvarchar(100), @UserPassword nvarchar(100)

-- Set the vars
SET @Database = '$(Database)' -- database name
SET @UserName = '$(UserName)' -- SQL login and database username
SET @UserPassword = '$(UserPassword)' -- login password

... more stuff here.. use the vars like normal
```

This is partly derived from [this blog post](https://www.dbbest.com/blog/using-powershell-invoke-sqlcmd-with-variable/) but modified slightly to use a file rather than an inline query.

Comment: I think this answer is more in the spirit of using PowerShell more than a command interpreter.  The SqlServer module is very powerful and flexible, but people get bogged down in TSQL and creating kludges with sqlcmd.  You also get the results in a more useful format than an executed application.

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting vonPryz's answer to use:

```
SET @dbName = '$(db)'
```

means you can pass in the parameter from the command line in a more natural form as

```
sqlcmd -S server\instance -E -v db ="foo" -i s.sql
```

The SqlCmd variable still substitutes correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old answer but I do have a better way that is much easier if you only need a small amount of data from Powershell (or even a large amount as long as all you want is text), and you work mainly in SQL for your scripting like I do:

1: Start the PowerShell from SQL using xp_cmdshell, and insert the results to a one-column table which allows NULLs e.g:

```
DECLARE @Results (Line varchar(1000) NULL)
INSERT @Results
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell '"powershell.exe C:\PowershellScripts\MyScript.ps1 MyParams"'
```

2: During your PowerShell script, for anything you want to pass back to SQL, simply use "Write-Output", e.g:

```
Write-Output $returned_data
```

You can do this as many times as you want. If you have 10,000 values to pass back to SQL, then you could use write-output 10,000 times.

So in the above example once the "MyScript.ps1" PowerShell script finishes running, all of the output will be in the @Results table variable, ready to be used, queried, imported into individual variables, whatever you want really.